vertical Gradient color for each bar is not working in a Grouped Bar Graph which has negative and positive bars using ChartJS
I am using Chart.js grouped bar chart. I want to show my bars with gradient colors. Grouped Bar  Currently it show as shown in below image. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
How to create a vertical grouped Bar chart(negative & positve bars) with vertical gradient from top to bottom of each bar bases on its height?
Here is my code click me to see code CodeSandbox

I found a very close solution here, but it sets the createLinearGradient for the whole graph, not for individual bars.
    import { Chart, Chart as ChartJS, registerables } from "chart.js";
import {
    getAxesTitle,
    getGridConfig,
    getLegendsConfig,
    getTooltipConfig,
    getZoomPanConfig,
    numDifferentiation
} from "./ChartJsConfig";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import annotationPlugin from "chartjs-plugin-annotation";
import { BarChartProps } from "types/Interfaces";
import { styleVariable } from "utils/UtilityFunc";
import zoomPlugin from "chartjs-plugin-zoom";

ChartJS.register(
    zoomPlugin,
    annotationPlugin,
    ...registerables
);

const BarChart = (props: BarChartProps) => {

    const { isShowGrid, isShowLegends, isShowTooltip, isZoomPan,
        isStacked, dataSet, zoomConfig, panConfig, annotation, titleInfo } = props;

    const chartContainer = useRef(null);

    function getScales() {
        return {
            x: {
                stacked: isStacked,
                ticks: {
                    color: styleVariable("--chart-scale"),
                    font: {
                        size: 11,
                        weight: "normal",
                        family: "NxtOption-Medium"
                    },
                    "callback": function (value: string | number) {
                        const newThis = this as any;
                        return newThis.getLabelForValue(value);
                    }
                },
                border: {
                    color: styleVariable("--chart-scale"),
                },
                title: getAxesTitle(titleInfo.x),
                grid: getGridConfig(isShowGrid)
            },
            y: {
                stacked: isStacked,
                ticks: {
                    color: styleVariable("--chart-scale"),
                    font: {
                        size: 11,
                        weight: "normal",
                        family: "NxtOption-Medium"
                    },
                    "callback": function (label: number) {
                        return numDifferentiation(label);
                    }
                },
                border: {
                    color: styleVariable("--chart-scale"),
                },
                title: getAxesTitle(titleInfo.y),
                grid: getGridConfig(isShowGrid)
            }
        };
    }

    function updateGradientColors(ctx: any, chartArea: any) {
        
        const redGradient = ctx && ctx.createLinearGradient(0, chartArea.top, 0, chartArea.bottom);
        if (redGradient) {
            redGradient.addColorStop(0.2, styleVariable("--bar-chart-red-top-color"));
            redGradient.addColorStop(1, styleVariable("--bar-chart-red-bottom-color"));
        }

        const greenGradient = ctx && ctx.createLinearGradient(0, chartArea.top, 0, chartArea.bottom);
        if (greenGradient) {
            greenGradient.addColorStop(0.2, styleVariable("--bar-chart-green-top-color"));
            greenGradient.addColorStop(1, styleVariable("--bar-chart-green-bottom-color"));
        }

        const gradientColors = [
            redGradient, greenGradient
        ];

        return gradientColors;
    }

    function getGradientColors() {
        if (chartContainer && chartContainer.current) {
            const normalColors = [
                styleVariable("--chart-call-oi-area-color"), 
                styleVariable("--chart-put-oi-area-color")
            ];
            
            return dataSet.datasets.map((dataset, idx) => {
                return {
                    ...dataset,
                    backgroundColor: function(context: any) {
                        const chart = context.chart;
                        const { ctx, chartArea } = chart;
                        if (!chartArea) return null;
                        const colors = updateGradientColors(ctx, chartArea);
                        if (colors.length)
                            return colors[ idx ];

                        return normalColors[ idx ];
                    }
                };
            });
        }

        return {};
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (chartContainer && chartContainer.current) {
            const configData = {
                type: "bar",
                "data": { ...dataSet, datasets: getGradientColors() },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    animation: false,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    interaction: {
                        mode: "index",
                    },
                    scales: getScales(),
                    plugins: {
                        legend: getLegendsConfig(isShowLegends),
                        zoom: getZoomPanConfig(isZoomPan, zoomConfig, panConfig),
                        tooltip: getTooltipConfig(isShowTooltip),
                        annotation: annotation ?? ""
                    },
                    layout: {
                        autoPadding: false,
                        padding: {
                            top: 50, 
                            bottom: 10,
                            left: 20,
                            right: 20
                        },
                    }
                }
                
            };
              
            const newChartInstance = new Chart(
                chartContainer.current,
                configData as any
            );
            
            return () => {
                newChartInstance.destroy();
            };
        }

        return () => {
            return "";
        };
    }, [
        chartContainer, dataSet
    ]);

    return (
        <div className="chartjs-container">
            <canvas ref={chartContainer} className="canvas-tag" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default BarChart;

Thanks in Advance.

To color each bar to full gradient from top to bottom, you have to adjust the  gradient backgroundColor to each bar. The (small) challenge is to identify the exact position of each bar in the graphical coordinates of the canvas. I think the code in this answer fits your requirements and needs minimal adaptation to your environment.
